# X86-asm code to make a usb disk non-bootable

Tags: assembly, x86, boot, bios, usb-mass-storage

we have developed a USB composite device (CDC and MSD classes) on a custom MCU-based hardware. The disk is a RAM disk (24 kb of space) and at power up, it is formatted (FAT 12) by the MCU vendor firmware. Unfortunately, the device is seen as a bootable disk and a typical BIOS tries to boot it. However, we know that connecting various USB disks to different PCs yields different results, depending both on the disk FAT type and on the BIOS behavior (obviously each BIOS has USB boot prior than HDD). **Our goal is to have an *unbootable* USB disk (FAT12 formatted)**.

We have tried many solutions but none worked. *In our opinion it seems BIOSes do more than simply checking the presence of a valid boot sector, copy the first sector to address 0x7C00 and jump at that address, giving control to the x86 ASM boot code.* In fact, we have formatted a commercial USB stick with Linux with the command:

```
mkdosfs -F 12 /dev/sda1
```

This USB stick has now a FAT12 Volume Boot Record and *we have not found to date a BIOS that gets stuck while trying to boot from it*.

Therefore, we copied its boot sector to our device and we expected it to work as the commercial USB stick. Nope: the BIOS hangs while trying to boot the disk. Here follows the disassembly of the boot sector generated by the above Linux command.

```
;Jump instructions
0x00007c00 eb 3c                            jmp    0x00007c3e
0x00007c02 90                               nop

;VBR segment
0x00007c03 6d                               
0x00007c04 6b 66 73 2e                      
0x00007c08 66 61                              

..............

;Boot code
0x00007c3e 0e                               push   %cs
0x00007c3f 1f                               pop    %ds
0x00007c40 be 5b 7c                         mov    $0x7c5b,%si
0x00007c43 ac                               lods   %ds:(%si),%al
0x00007c44 22 c0                            and    %al,%al
0x00007c46 74 0b                            je     0x00007c53
0x00007c48 56                               push   %si
0x00007c49 b4 0e                            mov    $0xe,%ah
0x00007c4b bb 07 00                         mov    $0x7,%bx
0x00007c4e cd 10                            int    $0x10
0x00007c50 5e                               pop    %si
0x00007c51 eb f0                            jmp    0x00007c43
0x00007c53 32 e4                            xor    %ah,%ah
0x00007c55 cd 16                            int    $0x16
0x00007c57 cd 19                            int    $0x19
0x00007c59 eb fe                            jmp    0x00007c59

;String to be displayed followed by zeros

0x00007c5b 54                               
0x00007c5c 68 69 73                         

..........

;Boot signature
0x00007dfe 55                               
0x00007dff aa
```

Apparently, the above code prints the string "This is not a bootable disk.  Please insert a bootable floppy and press any key to try again" and then calls INT16H and INT19H.

Why does the BIOS from the PC I am writing from, for example, prints: "Attempting boot from USB disk" and then jumps to my HDD while the same assembly code written in our device does not? That is, it writes "Please insert..."? There exists a code that can substitute this and never try to boot my custom USB disk?

In addition, does the BIOS do some special communications with a USB device before reading the first sector reading, for example, something from the device descriptor in order to understand if it can be used as a boot disk?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: From [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Bootloaders): *"If the bootsector of a disk contains a valid boot sector (the last word of the sector must contain the signature 0xAA55), then the disk is treated by the BIOS as bootable."* - if you do NOT want bootable disk, just don't mark sector 0 as bootable (by having the last two bytes to contain some different values than 0xAA55). With FAT12 the sector0 probably still should contain the geometry data, even if it is not bootable, I *guess*.

Comment: But maybe you should try to dump sector 0 from your device to see if the MCU firmware does not inject it's own 512B from some ROM, or patch yours... anyway, maybe just ask vendor what their firmware is doing (I mean, after you re-check few times that their firmware is a problem, and not your data). Also as you did create your own storage, go some extra length to verify it actually works as storage, i.e. when you set it to copy of that commercial USB, that it really returns that. EDIT: re-reading question: if  the MCU does reformat on power up, how do you keep anything there?

Comment: In addition to Ped7g's comment, have you tried marking the partition NOT bootable?

Comment: @Ped7g Only the MBRs on hard disks normally have the 0xAA55 signature. The VBR of a FAT12 bootblock normally doesn't have it. Traditionally BIOSs only look for the 0xAA55 when booting from a hard disk, when booting a floppy they execute the first sector regardless of the contents.

Comment: @MargaretBloom From the sounds of things the device isn't partitioned.

Comment: Oh, then this is completely beyond my knowledge (never looked into boot process too much), so my first comments are useless, sorry.

Comment: My guess is partitioning is at least part of the difference though. For `mkdosfs -F 12 /dev/sda1` to work the "commercial USB stick" would need to have been partitioned, as `/dev/sda1` refers to the first partition of the disk. This would also mean the first sector of the USB stick and the custom device are different. The USB stick has an MBR with a partition table in its first sector, while the custom device has the Linux FAT12 VBR in its first sector.

Comment: @RossRidge eh, I don't know. If the device really is an MSD and the OP is going to use it with other OSes but Linux/BSDs, it needs to be partitioned. As you said, it's unclear what the OP did.

Comment: Errata corrige: deleting 0xAA55 worked only on some PCs... others do halt at startup, it seems that some BIOSes hangs if they find an invalid partition.

Comment: @Ped7g We have the source code of the firmware so we edited the format function of the firmware vendor to make the first sector the same as the commercial USB stick. Our device reformat at power up and writes some read-only files on the disk.

Comment: @RossRidge You are right, our device is not partitioned. But the first sector (the first 512 bytes) of the Linux formatted commercial USB stick and of our device are made identical, they are both VBR, so no partition. I don't know why Linux recognizes our as sda and the commercial one as sda1. I have posted above the first 512 bytes, no partition table there.

Comment: I still don't understand the symptoms. You plug your device into a PC and when booting it *halts*?

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes, the BIOS tries to boot from our USB device as if it were bootable and then it halts.

Comment: The code you posted should display a string at least (not necessarily the correct one though), at first glance, I can't see any major issue. But nothing is displayed, right? So, how can you be sure that your code is actually being executed? Usually, a device is either booted or not, if the PC halts it must be due to the code executed or some BIOS bug/incompatibility.

Comment: @MargaretBloom With the commercial USB stick the BIOS prints: "Attempting to boot from USB device" but it does not print the string written in the first sector and jumps to HDD. Our device, same assembly, same PC, the BIOS prints the string "This is not a bootable disk...." etc. and then it halts.

Comment: The INT 19h is used to do a warm reset. If after pressing a key (INT 16h) the PC halts it means the implementation of INT 19h has some issues but that's off-topic. You could try inspecting the MBR of the commercial USB stick and see what makes it not-bootable (I thought a missing signature was enough, but CSM are weird) or in the worst make a VBR that calls INT 18h.

Comment: @Cesare The command `mkdosfs -F 12 /dev/sda1` doesn't change or modify the first sector of the disk containing the MBR and the partition table. It only changes the first sector of the first partition which is not the first sector of the disk. If you used that command on your commercial USB stick then that means that contents first sector of the commercial USB stick are completely different then the Linux FAT12 VBR code you posted. Your commercial USB stick would have MBR code in its first sector instead.

Comment: @RossRidge Hi Ross, thank you, this shed some light on the problem. You were right, we weren't looking at the first sector but at the first partition. It seems to be impossibile to have an unbootable fat12 partition. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately there may not anything to prevent your custom USB device from used as a boot device on any PC it might be plugged into. However there are couple of things you can do that should cover most cases, the first is not to have the 0xAA55 signature at the end of the boot sector and the second is to invoke INT 0x18 the boot sector to ask the BIOS to try the next boot device.

#### How BIOSes boot USB devices

The basic problem is here is that there's no standard for BIOS booting of USB mass storage devices. How exactly a BIOS might go about determining if a USB device is bootable varies between BIOS implementations. There are however two basic steps all implementations will follow.

The first is to determine whether to emulate the USB device as a "floppy", "hard drive", "cdrom", "zip" or other kind of drive. For your device it should come down to choosing between floppy or hard drive emulation. Various criteria are possible for making the this choice, like the size of the drive, whether its reports itself as being removable and the command set used. In particular there's an upper limit to the size of a drive floppy emulation can support, about 530MB I believe, and this size is often used for determining the device type. Some BIOSes can also be configured to force a certain device type in their settings.

The next step is to determine whether the device is bootable. This means at the very least reading the first sector of the drive, since if it can't be read it can't be booted.  Then the BIOS may try to determine if the boot sector is valid. If it's emulating a hard drive it should always check for the presence of the 0xAA55 signature, but if it's emulating a floppy it may or may not perform this check. If it's emulating a hard drive it might also check for a valid MBR-style partition, and if's emulating a floppy it might check for a valid FAT BIOS Parameter Block (BPB).

So not having the 0xAA55 magic number at the end of the boot sector would prevent the USB device from being used a boot device in at least some cases. However it's most likely that the BIOS will choose to use floppy emulation for your device, and many BIOSes won't do any validation of the boot sector beyond verifying it's readable. However, if you can have your USB device pretend it's much larger than it actually is, beyond what floppy emulation supports, then it should make it far more likely for hard drive emulation to be used.

#### Invoking INT 0x18

However all is not lost even if the the BIOS does load and execute the boot sector of your device. You can invoke INT 0x18, which originally was used to start cassette BASIC on an original IBM PC, but was redefined by the BIOS Boot Specification to be the recovery vector for failed boot attempts. On a modern PC, including any that supports booting USB devices, invoking this will tell the BIOS to try the next boot device. (INT 0x18 is actually called after a boot failure in standard MBR implementations back since the MBR was invented, so it's not actually as unusual as it might sound.)

Here's the source code for a boot sector that invokes INT 0x18 I used for testing on various PCs I had available:

```
    .code16

    .text

    jmp start
    nop
    .org    0x03    # insure a two byte long JMP insn was used

    .org    0x3e    # skip over FAT BIOS Parameter Block
start:
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $0x7c00, %sp

    call    print_message

    .ascii  "\r\nOOPS... The BIOS tried to boot the custom device.\r\n"
    .byte   0

    xor %ax, %ax
    int $0x16       # read from keyboard

    # Try using the BIOS Boot Specification's recovery vector so
    # that BIOS tries another boot device. On an a real 5150 IBM PC
    # this starts cassette BASIC.  On a PC that doesn't support the
    # BBS then it may print an error message, do nothing or crash.

    int $0x18

    call    print_message

    # INT 0x18 didn't work, didn't start BASIC and didn't crash.
    # Print an error message to user and invoke the INT 0x19
    # reboot vector.

    .ascii  "\r\nRemove the custom device and press any key to reboot"
    .ascii  " the computer.\r\n"
    .byte   0

    xor %ax, %ax
    int $0x16       # read from keyboard

    int $0x19       # reboot

infinite_loop:
    jmp infinite_loop

print_message:
    pop %si
loop_message:
    lods    %cs:(%si), %al
    test    %al,%al
    jz  end_message
    mov $0xe, %ah
    mov $0x7, %bx
    int $0x10       # print a character
    jmp loop_message
end_message:
    jmp *%si

    .org    0x1FF
    .byte   00      # note no 55 aa signature
```

You should be able to modify this code for use with your device. Make sure to copy the FAT12 BPB (the bytes between offsets 0x003 and 0x03e) from your device's BPB. You'll probably want to remove the first invocation of INT 0x16 which waits for a key press before invoking INT 0x18. To assemble and link the code you can use the following commands:

```
as -o myfat12.o myfat12.s
ld --oformat=binary -o myfat12.bin -Ttext=0x7c00 myfat12.o
```

To copy the BPB from your device into the boot sector created with the above commands you can use something like:

```
dd conv=notrunc if=/dev/sda of=myfat12.bin bs=1 skip=3 seek=3 count=59
```

In my testing it the code above worked fairly well, but in one case the BIOS just tried the same boot device over and over again. In an another case the PC (a 15 year-old Pentium 4) crashed when trying to boot the code off a USB flash drive, but not off of an actual USB floppy disk. The crash was probably related the unusual 24k FAT12 BPB I was using to try to replicate your device as closely as possible.

The second "Remove the custom device..." message was never printed in my testing. Either the boot block was never executed in the first place or invoking 0x18 did something and never returned. You might want to move those instructions to the first message in case INT 0x18 doesn't do anything helpful.

Comment: Hello Ross! I tried your solution on our device. Many BIOSes do work as you said. However, on some new Dell Laptop with modern BIOSes the device simply halts the boot process (no string displayed in this case). Unfortunately we can't sell the device with this problem so we did some kind of trick that is to delay our device firmware startup after power on, not elegant but did the work. Nevertheless I marked your answer as accepted since it is really complete and full of details. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling INT 18H, this is specified by the BIOS Boot Specification (Compaq, Phoenix, Intel 1996) to try the next boot device.

Alternatively it may need to load the bootsector of the next disk by itself using INT 13H.